# loading data into hazelcast at run-time

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast IMDG in my application.

I'm doing three different step one by one:

Step:1

When I start the application I'm loading table data into hazelcast IMap.

After Loading:-

Step:-2

I'm filtering some data using Hazelcast SqlPredicate.

```
String sql="this.age <= 30
SqlPredicate predicateForObjs = new SqlPredicate(sql);
Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> filterResult = dataEntity.values(predicateForObjs);
```

Step:- 3

Again I'm loading the filtered result into one more map for doing the sort operation.

```
IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> sortMap= hazelCast.getMap("data");

int i=0;
for(HazelcastJsonValue hjv : filterResult ){
sortMap.put(i,hjv);
i++;

}

Comparator<Entry<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue>> descendingComparator = new DescendingIdComparator();
PagingPredicate pagingPredicate = Predicates.pagingPredicate(descendingComparator, sortMap.size());
Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> values = map.values(pagingPredicate);
```

for doing the sort operation I'm loading filtered result at run time.

I have seen many articles saying that loading data into cache at run time is not good and also kills the performance.

Can anyone suggest diff approach.?

Am I using correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Hazelcast Jet job for the data ingestion. Jet job can connect to the [data source](https://jet-start.sh/docs/next/api/sources-sinks), [filter](https://jet-start.sh/docs/next/api/stateless-transforms#filter) the data and [sort](https://jet-start.sh/docs/next/api/stateful-transforms#sort) it prior to [writing it](https://jet-start.sh/docs/next/api/sources-sinks#map-sink) to the IMap.

You can start a standalone Jet cluster to run the job to reduce the stress on your Hazelcast IMDG data cluster.